# How to default to a value in SQL to use for a join if conditions aren't met

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, case

I hope I can explain this clearly.

I have a four digit NAICS code lookup table that I am trying to join some records to. The root table has a six-digit NAICS code that I trim and compare to the table (emd) that I want to join to. There are three conditions that I want to join to emd on:

1. State from root table (x) matches emd
2. The year in the emd table is the max year in emd for that state
3. The NAICS code in table x matches the NAICS code in table emd

WHEN #3 is not met, I want the query to use '0000' as the NAICS code.

I.E. - If a record from table X with NAICS "6242" and State "AZ" exists, but table emd doesn't have a corresponding row for "AZ' with "6242", I want to use the "AZ" row with "0000".

I will paste the query below. To initially get this to kind of work, on the join to table emd, I added a case statement, basically saying "If the NAICS codes match, use it. Otherwise, use "0000". However, that is creating duplication.

When I test the query and run a query for a state that does have a NAICS code in the table (not 0000), it still returns a row for the '0000' entry for the corresponding state.

Let me know if you need more information! I can't figure this out.

```
select x.NAICS, x.StateProvince, x.StateProvinceCode,
emd.FinalDemandOutput,
(x.JobsMaintained * isnull(wd.AvgSalary2017, 0)) * emd.FinalDemandOutput TotalEconomicImpact,
(x.HeadcountExtrapolated * isnull(wd.AvgSalary2017, 0)) * emd.FinalDemandOutput TotalEconomicImpact_HC,
st.MinWage,  
x.JobsMaintained * isnull(wd.AvgSalary2017, 0) TotalWages,  
x.HeadcountExtrapolated * isnull(wd.AvgSalary2017, 0) TotalWages_HC,
from(
select c.CorporationKey, c.SupplierKey, c.SurveyPeriodKey, sp.year, sp.Quarter, sp.QuarterNum, c.Headcount, c.PYAllocatedRevenue,
c.PYAllocatedJob, c.CYAllocatedRevenue, c.extrapolationfactor, left(concat(ic.Code, '000000'), 6) NAICS, sl.Description StateProvince, 
sl.StateCode StateProvinceCode,
(jm.Pct * c.Headcount)  as JobsMaintained,
c.CSId_, c.CSSupplierId_, c.ImpactFactor3_Annual, ((c.Headcount/c.extrapolationfactor) * c.ImpactFactor3_Annual) HeadcountExtrapolated 
from x
left join WageData wd on Substring(left(concat(x.NAICS, '000000'), 6), 1,4) = substring(wd.NAICS, 1, 4)
left join EconomicMultiplierData4DigitNAICS emd on x.StateProvince = emd.statename 
        and emd.year = (select max(emd2.year) from EconomicMultiplierData4DigitNAICS emd2 where emd2.statename = x.StateProvince)
        and (case when Substring(left(concat(x.NAICS, '000000'), 6), 1,4) = substring(emd.NAICS, 1, 4)
        then Substring(left(concat(x.NAICS, '000000'), 6), 1,4) 
        else '0000' 
        end) = substring(emd.NAICS, 1, 4)
```

Comment: Look up ISNULL or COALESCE.

Comment: Looking at your query here is painful. It isn't valid because you have a ")" on the third line. But I can't even pretend to unravel this wall of text into anything manageable. Don't be scared to use which space and formatting to make your queries legible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is incredibly hard to read, but I think you want something like this:

For the join:

```
left join EconomicMultiplierData4DigitNAICS emd on x.StateProvince = emd.statename 
    and emd.year = (select max(emd2.year) from EconomicMultiplierData4DigitNAICS emd2   where emd2.statename = x.StateProvince)
    and emd.NAICS = x.NAICS
```

For the Select:

```
ISNULL(emd.NAICS,'000000')
```

Left join will return NULL, then you can use ISNULL to instead select your default value of '000000' in that situation.

EDIT: After comment below, this instead may be closer to the desired result:
For the join:

```
left join EconomicMultiplierData4DigitNAICS emd on x.StateProvince = emd.statename 
    and emd.year = (select max(emd2.year) from EconomicMultiplierData4DigitNAICS emd2   where emd2.statename = x.StateProvince)
    and emd.NAICS = x.NAICS
left join EconomicMultiplierData4DigitNAICS emdFallback on x.StateProvince = emdFallback.statename 
    and emdFallback.year = (select max(emd2.year) from EconomicMultiplierData4DigitNAICS emd2   where emd2.statename = x.StateProvince)
    and emdFallback.NAICS = '000000'
```

For the Select:

```
ISNULL(emd.[FieldName],emdFallback.[FieldName]) [FieldName]
```

This does make the select a bit more tedious, and may need a DISTINCT.

I imagine there is a better/more clever way to do what you want, though I can't think of it at the moment.

Comment: Close! However, I don't just want '000000' to show up. I want it to use the values in the edm table for the '000000' record. That '000000' value isn't a null, it has corresponding data in the edm table. There are a few of the columns that populate based on the edm join.

Comment: Oh! Okay I misunderstood the goal, I'll think about that further.

Comment: Updated the answer a bit at the bottom, I think this is closer to what you want, but it does mean you'd be using ISNULL() around all the emd fields.